# Eigenvectors of a sum of PSD matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory, positive-semidefinite

Lets say I have two real-valued positive-semidefinite matrices $A$ and $B$ with eigenvectors given by $v_i$ and $w_i$, respectively. Does this tell me anything about the eigenvectors of
$C = A + B$

I am particularly interested in the case where A and B are matrices related to graphs (e.g. adjacency matrices, laplacians etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't.
$A$ and $B$ could be the identity matrix $I$ (for which any sequences of nonzero vectors are eigenvectors).  And then any sequence of nonzero vectors are eigenvectors of $C=2I$ as well.

Things might be a little more interesting if you assumed that $A$ and $B$ have distinct eigenvalues.

EDIT: We may assume $v_i$ and $w_i$ are orthonormal bases.
Suppose you want the members of orthonormal basis $u_i$ to be eigenvectors of $A+B$.  These vectors form the columns of orthogonal matrices $S, T, U$ respectively,
where $D_A = S^\top A S$, $D_B = T^\top B T$ and $D_C = U^\top C U$ are all diagonal with diagonal entries the eigenvalues of $A, B, C$ respectively.  But you need $A+B = C$, i.e. $S D_A S^\top + T D_B T^\top = U D_C U^\top$, or equivalently
$ U^\top (S D_A S^\top + T D_B T^\top) U$ is diagonal.  This matrix is certainly symmetric, but if the matrices are
$n \times n$ there are $n(n-1)/2$ entries above the diagonal that must be $0$.  There are $n(n-1)/2$ conditions to satisfy with only $2n$ free variables (the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$).  There are always two linearly independent solutions where $A$ and $B$ are multiples
of the identity.  But  if
$n$ is large enough we might not have a solution other than those.

For example, I tried the $6 \times 6$ matrices
$$ S = \frac{1}{15} \left[ \begin {array}{cccccc} -4&3&-8&6&-8&6\\ -3&-
4&-6&-8&-6&-8\\ -8&6&-4&3&8&-6\\ -
6&-8&-3&-4&6&8\\ -8&6&8&-6&-4&3\\ 
-6&-8&6&8&-3&-4\end {array} \right],
\ T = \frac{1}{15} \left[ \begin {array}{cccccc} 4&8&8&-3&-6&-6\\ 8&4&
-8&-6&-3&6\\8&-8&4&-6&6&-3\\ 3&6&
6&4&8&8\\ 6&3&-6&8&4&-8\\ 6&-6&3&8
&-8&4\end {array} \right],\ U = I $$
and found that indeed the only solutions are where $D_A$ and $D_B$ are multiples of the identity.  So in this case
the basis $\{u_i\}$ is not going to be arbitrary.  On the
other hand, to state explicitly what bases are possible
is not going to be simple.

Comment: what happens if they have distinct eigenvalues?